# Select from drop down menu or add another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I'm using simple_form. How can I have a select menu and a text input and have something like `Select or add another`.

The app will only take one value, either from the select menu or the text input.

It would also be good to validate to have either one or the other but not both, to avoid user confusion.

Comment: To clarify, you want a select menu populated with existing values to choose from, and a text input for adding a value not already listed in the select menu. Correct? With a single submit button?

Comment: correct. if there is a value on the text input, the app will use that value. if there is a value on the select menu, the app will use that one. if there is a value on the text input and on the select menu, a validation error should pop up.

Answer (score 1):

Implement what is called a 'combobox' to your simple_form

Jquery UI has a combobox:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox

something fancier:
http://demos.kendoui.com/web/combobox/index.html

This will get you as far as your combo boxes displaying. I don't think there is a plugin for validating, so you'll have to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a combination of JavaScript and Ruby to solve this. If a user wants to enter a different value then what's available in the dropdown, you should have JS listen to a keydown event in that input and clear the dropdown, i.e.:

```
$(".input_field").bind('keydown', function() {
  $(".select_field").val('0') // this should be a default blank value
});
```

That will clear the select when a user types. Likewise, you want to clear the input when the user selects from the dropdown, right?

```
$(".select_field").change(function() {
  // Let's only clear the input field if the value is not the default null value
  if ( $(this).val() != 0 ) {
    $(".input_field").val('');
  }
});
```

This will handle the front-end interactions. In the controller, you'll want to do some additional logic:

```
def create
  object.new(...)
  if params[:select] and params[:input]
    # Overwrite the select with the input value
    object.attribute = params[:input]
  end
  object.save
end
```

I assume that you want the input value to supersede the select, therefore if they are most submitted, we can just overwrite the select value with the input value and then continue to save the object.

Is this what you're looking for? Not sure if the inputted value was suppose to create a new object with a relationship or not. Hope this helps.